# Visual Studio project execution stopped shortly after starting

Tags: visual-studio

Yesterday I wanted to continue working on a project of mine, so I started Visual Studio and asked it to run the project to remind myself, what was already implemented and what wasn't.

The project got built and started, but seemed to quit right away. No error message, nothing.
No matter what I did, whether I rebuilt the project or cleaned it, nothing changed.
This didn't make sense, since the last time I tested the project, it worked perfectly (and I didn't modify anything in the code since then)

So, I assumed I had a hidden bug somewhere in the code, that just didn't show up previously.
I put a Breakpoint somewhere near the beginning of the code, and ran the project.

As expected, Visual Studio paused the execution at the Breakpoint and highlighted it.
I decided to set another Breakpoint somewhere later in the code and continue execution, but before I could even move my mouse, the project stopped.

Restarting Visual Studio didn't help, but restarting the PC did. Therefore, I'm assuming that something on my system was terminating my project, shortly after execution begun.

Now my question is: What exactly happened, and especially: why did it happen?

The problem came back while I was writing this question. I don't feel like restarting my PC every couple of hours...

I really appreciate the time you took reading this and I look forward to your answers.

Comment: Hope you don't expect us to come over and look into the matter!!LOL There are few bugs in the VS2010, check out the MS site or use their Bug reporting and tracking to find out whats wrong. That usually doesn't help much either. We are as helpless as you are in this matter. I dont think anybody on SO could come to you aide.

Comment: Could you be more specific. What type of the project is it? Is is e.g. ASP.Net or WinForms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm aware that I'm answering my own question, but since I've solved it myself, I thought others might want to know how I did it (for the sake of future generations)

The thing is: I've recently added Visual C++ to Visual C# before Visual C# started having problems.
So I deduced, that maybe the installer for Visual Studio messed up with something and decided to reinstall Visual Studio.

Problem solved.

So: if your projects stop without warning even while paused on a Breakpoint and you've changed something in your Visual Studio installation (like added Visual C++ in my case), you might need to reinstall the whole thing.
Luckily, the Visual Studio installer offers a "Reinstall" option, so you don't need to uninstall and reinstall manually.

I found about this solution, after talking to a more experienced colleague. I just wish I asked him first. Still appreciate your efforts in the matter, though.

EDIT:
I recently noticed a similar bug acting up for C++ programs this time, where the window border would be outlined in red. The thing is: it's not Visual Studio's fault, but in fact Avast Antivirus' fault. More specifically, its Sandbox mode.

So, if for any reason, you notice programs quitting without crashing, shortly after starting and their window border having a red outline, you're very likely using Avast Antivirus and should deactivate the Sandbox mode.

Comment: This is so respectable to people who are having the  same problem. Thank You for posting the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Happens to me from time to time.

Sometimes closing and opening VS helps, sometimes you have to restart the computer.

I assume it must be related to some DLL or something that is loaded into memory and corrupt, or something like VS loosing the reference to it, and not unloading it correctly/replacing it.

I also once had this strange bug, where I started VS, just like any other day, and my project crashes instantly with some H_RESULT error (some DLL related Error) upon run. After having spent around 1hour searching for  the source of the problem, I went into the reference section, and what did I see there : the worst possible circular reference ever : my business project had a reference to ... itself ! The kind of stuff you could not do if you wanted to.

The weirdest part of this, must of been that VS managed to compile the project, and it only crashed while trying to run it ...